# How does the syntax in a if/then/else within a do block work in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make the folowing function:

```
repcountIORIban :: IORef -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Lock -> IORef -> Lock -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
repcountIORIban count number lower modulus amountthreads lock done lock2 difference rest = do
        if rest > number
            then let extra = 1
            else let extra = 0
        if number + 1 < amountthreads
            then
                forkIO $ realcountIORIban(count lower (lower + difference + extra - 1) modulus lock done lock2)
                repcountIORIban (count (number + 1) (lower + difference + extra) modulus amountthreads lock done lock2 difference rest)
            else
                forkIO $ realcountIORIban(count lower (lower + difference + extra - 1) modulus lock done lock2)
```

But I can't run the program from which this function is a part of. It gives me the error:

```
error: parse error on input `else'
    |
113 |             else let extra = 0
    |             ^^^^
```

I've got this error a lot of times withing my program but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You appear to be trying to call the `IORef` bound to `count` as if it were a function. Aside from that, it seems it would be a lot easier to populate a list using `repcountIORIban`, then map `forkIO` over it.

Answer (score 5):

This is incorrect, you can't `let` after `then`/`else` and expect those `let`s to define bindings which are visible below.

```
do if rest > number
     then let extra = 1  -- wrong, needs a "do", or should be "let .. in .."
     else let extra = 0
   ... -- In any case, extra is not visible here
```

Try this instead

```
do let extra = if rest > number
               then 1
               else 0
   ...
```

Further, you need `then do` if after that you need to perform two or more actions.

```
if number + 1 < amountthreads
  then do
    something
    somethingElse
  else         -- use do here if you have two or more actions
    ...
```

Comment: Even if I change it to that, the compilers gives me an error. Now it says that extra is not is scope in the other if/then/else block.

Comment: @JoesdeJonge That `extra` is definitely in scope where I wrote the `...` in the code above. I can not guess which error you are getting, so I can not provide any help. You could open a new question with that new error.

Comment: @schuelermine Why would `extra` not be on scope, once the code is changed as shown above?

Comment: @JoesdeJonge can you post your new code [like on pastebin]?